# Can I repeat steps without repeating the steps using Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I need to test behaviour that triggers when a user repeats a set of actions many times. I would like to end up with a scenario that looks something like this:

```
Scenario: Nice way
  Given that I am on some screen
  When I enter something into some text field
  And I press the Continue button
  And I go back
  And I repeat the previous 2 steps 5 times
  Then the application should crash
```

Rather than a scenario that looks like this:

```
Scenario: Annoying way
  Given that I am on some screen
  When I enter something into some text field
  And I press the Continue button
  And I go back
  And I press the Continue button
  And I go back
  And I press the Continue button
  And I go back
  And I press the Continue button
  And I go back
  And I press the Continue button
  And I go back
  And I press the Continue button
  And I go back
  Then the application should crash
```

Is there a standard way of doing this or do I have to implement it myself?

Comment: Thats one nice application you're specifying here (`Then the application should crash`)

Comment: Why would you want the application to crash? This seems like an exploratory test, not a design test. I wouldn't do it in cucumber.

Comment: @DaveMcNulla The application shouldn't crash. The example is made up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have control over the step definition code try a step like this -

```
And I press Continue button and go back 5 times
```

Capture the number of times in the step definition with a variable and call existing functions in a loop for the number of times.

It can be captured by something like:

```
@And("^I press Continue button and go back (//d+) times")
public void iPressContinueButtonAndGoBackNTimes(int n){
    //enter code here
}
```

Comment: That is one way, but it means that I have to create a new step definition for every scenario where I need to repeat some steps. I guess that is acceptable, but not ideal.

Comment: Well you can even catch the  'Continue' part and the 'back' part in variables and see if you can reuse for similar scenarios with different pair of actions. Or get creative and setup a factory of actions which you can instantiate with whatever keyword you using in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat arbitrary steps without having to write a new one each time, define this step

```
When /^I repeat "([^"]*)" (\d+) times$/ do |steps, times|
  times.to_i.times do
    steps.split(/;\s*/).each do |step|
      step step
    end
  end
end
```

and use it like this:

```
When I repeat "press the Continue button; go back" 5 times
```

(And don't use semicolons in the names of steps that you want to repeat.)

Comment: Thanks, but I went with Grasshopper's suggestion, because it makes the scenario more readable.